# Make duplicates in varchar field not duplicate by adding an incrementing number

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm upgrading a DB schema. A table is divided into 2 tables. These two tables are linked and the only way to link them is using a varchar name field in the original table.

Problem is that customer *could* have duplicate names, since name is not the Primary/Unique Key.

I came here looking for ideas to make these names unique so it can be used as a key when moving the data to the two new linked tables.

As I'm writing this, I had the idea of CONCATing the current PK to name (as in CONCAT(name,id) as newName) and use this as key.

There's also a unique code field, but this only goes into one of the new tables.

Example Schema:

```
tableA
a_id INT(11) PRI AUTO_INCREMENT
code VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE 
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL

newTableB
b_id INT(11) PRI AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR(30)

newTableC
c_id INT(11) PRI AUTO_INCREMENT
b_id INT(11) FK->newTableB
code VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE
```

What I want:

1. Generate New b_id's (auto_increment)
2. newTableB.name imported from tableA.name
3. newTableC.code imported from tableA.code
4. newTableC.c_id imported from tableA.a_id

a_id is an FK in another fourth table that's staying the same. After the changes above, c_id will now be valid FK in this fourth table.

**My Challenge:** 
How Do insert into these new tables but still keep the original name<->code<->a_id relationship and transfer tableA.a_id values to newTableC.c_id. Don't care if b_id gets new auto_incr. values.

Not sure how clear I'm making problem come across, but feel free to ask any questions.

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've usually done a task like this in several parts. First insert to table b but put the id field from a in the name column instead of the name. Then insert the data into tablec from table a. Then update tableb name field by joining to table a on the a.id and b.name fields. BUt im not sure if you can use a join in an update in mysql. Should bea way to write the statement though once you have the data there.

Alternatively, I temporarily add a column to table b called tableid. Then I put the data in tableb including the a id and use that to join to table a to get the b.id and table A data for table c. When it is done, I drop the tableA column from table b.

Comment: I've read your comment twice and it's hard to imagine it in my head, I'll have to run it through step by step, but I think you're on the right track with adding the a_id in to the name column temporarily. I'm sure you could do a join on update.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
CREATE TABLE temp_newTableB AS (SELECT * FROM newTableB);
DELETE FROM newTableB WHERE b_id NOT IN (SELECT b_id FROM temp_newTableB GROUP BY name);
DROP TABLE temp_newTableB ;
```

but is there any rule on which you are going to decide which `b_id` you want to keep in the `newTableC` as some of the duplicate named `b_id` will be removed from `newTableB` by the above query??

Comment: newTableB is empty so I'm not sure what your query is doing. It is also deleting the duplicate names, I want to keep them.

Comment: Well this is supposed to delete the duplicate names from newTableB......But you said that you want to keep them, then where do you want to make them unique I mean in which table?

Comment: I guess what I was trying to do is make them unique just to use it as a key. But I think HLGEM had a better idea with adding a_id temporarily to do the inserts then remove it.